# How to remove the escape characters in Redshift query

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have some sql for a column that looks like this:

```
JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(JSON_SERIALIZE(after), 'educations', 'string') as educations,
```

and the resulting value is this:

```
[{\"id\": \"Mumbai University\", \"type\": \"\", \"selected\": true, \"displayName\": \"Mumbai University\"}]
```

How do I store that value as json without the escapes? What should I do?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having to do the same thing.